# what are the file compression algorithms available for txt file compression?

Tags: file, compression

I am in a project for developing a s/w for file compression(text oriented) that gives effective results. I searched this site but no question has been answered with the basics of file compression. I am ok with java,c,c++ for coding. Kindly suggest me some websites, books and specific algorithms to do this. And how to look at the coding of standard file compression s/w s available? Thanks for considering this too basic question..

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly your question, what about Java Compression API: [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Or, if you want to implement your own algorithm, check for the two Huffman coding (static and dynamic), the Arithmetic coding or the LZW coding (since `the Ziv-Lempel compression scheme can be proved to be asymptotically optimal` from the paper `Text Data Compression Algorithms` by Maxime Crochemore and Thierry Lecroq, 1997) and implement your own source code. The paper contains some meta-implementation for the algorithms I suggested, I did not check this meta-implementation out but probably are gonna be quite straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Following are some of the best known and can be easily implemented file compression algorithms and mostly all of them suitable for text files as they provide lossless compression.

[Run-length encoding (RLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

[Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)

Lempel-Ziv compression (LZ77 and LZ78)

DEFLATE – Combines Lempel-Ziv

Lempel–Ziv–Markov chain algorithm (LZMA)

Lempel–Ziv–Oberhumer (LZO)

Lempel–Ziv–Storer–Szymanski (LZSS)

Lempel–Ziv–Welch (LZW)